# Android Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD Vs WindowsPhone Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

In SensorChanged event, event.values has value[0],value[1] and value[2] in Android.

> value[0] is equivalent to e.SensorReading.MagneticHeading in Windows
>   Phone.

Like that i want to know the equivalent values of value[1] and value[2]. Can anyone please define this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, according to [Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values), the `value` array  corresponds to the micro-tesla readings of the magnetometer in the X, Y and Z directions. If you look at the MSDN docs for the [CompassReading Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.compassreading%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) the `MagnetometerReading` will give you a `Vector3` providing the raw magnetometer readings from the device.

One thing to note is that the MSDN docs specifically call out that these are **raw** readings where as the Android docs don't specify this. As such you'll probably get very different readings between the two systems.

MSDN has a good article on [How to: Get Data from the Compass Sensor for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202974%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which would be a good starting point.